# VS 2012: How to set project dependencies without changin build order?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, build, build-process, projects-and-solutions

I have a Visual Studio solution and I want to setup project dependencies in following way:

- Project A needs project B during **runtime**. E.g. when someone *Builds* project A, project B should also be built (unless it is up-to-date).
- Project A does NOT depend on project B in **compile-time** (e.g. it doesn't statically link to project B etc.). Therefore they can be built in parallel.

If I set in Project Dependencies dialog for Project A that it depends on Project B, Project A will be built only after project B is finished building. Because I have about 100 projects in a solution, this significantly slows down build.

So my question is: can I setup dependencies in the way that Project A requires project B, but they could compile in parallel?

### Update

The most common case when we run into problem is when someone just forgets to build the solution before launch. When dependencies are set, VS brings up a prompt to build all projects depending on startup project. When there is no project dependency and project B was modified, VS doesn't issue any message to user, and this usually results in nasty runtime errors.

At the moment we are using following workaround: project A does **not** have dependency set on project B, and we set `Projects and Solutions` -> `Build and Run` -> `Only build startup projects and dependencies on run` to false (not checked). However, this is a global setting, not a solution option. So I wonder if there is more correct way to solve this problem.

Comment: So don't set the build dependency.  Kinda obvious, no?

Comment: @HansPassant This doesn't meet the first requirement `when someone Builds project A, project B should also be built`. E.g. project A uses binaries of project B **in runtime**, therefore when someone builds and launches project A, project's B binaries should also be up-to-date.

Comment: Why would B not be built?  You build a solution, not a project.  It is not like it is impossible to build just one project in a solution, it is available from the context menu.  Just don't do that.

Comment: @HansPassant thanks for your suggestion. Yes, that makes sense (always build a solution). I've updated the question to explain the problem. I just wonder if there is an option or smth that I'm not aware about :)